# Esri mapview USGS earthquake trigger popup from outside of map

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geojson, esri-geodatabase, usgs

I am trying to show some recent earthquake information in Esri maps using USGS earthquake API data. I am able to fetch the list from API data and also I got the map with those listed information indicated on map using orange circles.

Check below JsFiddle link..

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wcd9ub8f/)**

[image]

In this above screenshot you can able to see the popup that shows the detailed information of specific area when clicking that orange circle.

In the left side area also I am fetching the details from API data. I want to show the popup when I click from the left side lists too. How can I trigger the click event and show the popup?

***Js Code:***

```
var object = {"type":"FeatureCollection","metadata":{"generated":1564051101000,"url":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2019-07-20&endtime=2019-07-21&minmagnitude=5","title":"USGS Earthquakes","status":200,"api":"1.8.1","count":4},"features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":5.2000000000000002,"place":"79km ENE of L'Esperance Rock, New Zealand","time":1563662132538,"updated":1563663302040,"tz":-720,"url":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us70004pu1","detail":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us70004pu1&format=geojson","felt":null,"cdi":null,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"reviewed","tsunami":0,"sig":416,"net":"us","code":"70004pu1","ids":",us70004pu1,","sources":",us,","types":",geoserve,origin,phase-data,","nst":null,"dmin":1.9299999999999999,"rms":1.28,"gap":70,"magType":"mww","type":"earthquake","title":"M 5.2 - 79km ENE of L'Esperance Rock, New Zealand"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-178.1173,-31.174800000000001,35]},"id":"us70004pu1"},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":5.5999999999999996,"place":"23km NNW of Kandrian, Papua New Guinea","time":1563655424914,"updated":1563741959328,"tz":600,"url":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us70004psn","detail":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us70004psn&format=geojson","felt":1,"cdi":4.2999999999999998,"mmi":4.4779999999999998,"alert":"green","status":"reviewed","tsunami":1,"sig":483,"net":"us","code":"70004psn","ids":",us70004psn,","sources":",us,","types":",dyfi,geoserve,losspager,moment-tensor,origin,phase-data,shakemap,","nst":null,"dmin":3.2029999999999998,"rms":0.89000000000000001,"gap":28,"magType":"mww","type":"earthquake","title":"M 5.6 - 23km NNW of Kandrian, Papua New Guinea"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[149.5069,-6.0086000000000004,59.789999999999999]},"id":"us70004psn"},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":5.0999999999999996,"place":"Easter Island region","time":1563647034336,"updated":1563892918040,"tz":-420,"url":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us70004pra","detail":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us70004pra&format=geojson","felt":null,"cdi":null,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"reviewed","tsunami":0,"sig":400,"net":"us","code":"70004pra","ids":",us70004pra,","sources":",us,","types":",geoserve,origin,phase-data,","nst":null,"dmin":2.7559999999999998,"rms":0.71999999999999997,"gap":118,"magType":"mb","type":"earthquake","title":"M 5.1 - Easter Island region"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-111.38379999999999,-29.3232,10]},"id":"us70004pra"},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":5.0999999999999996,"place":"136km ESE of Pangai, Tonga","time":1563635789233,"updated":1563636880040,"tz":-720,"url":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us70004pp5","detail":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us70004pp5&format=geojson","felt":null,"cdi":null,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"reviewed","tsunami":0,"sig":400,"net":"us","code":"70004pp5","ids":",us70004pp5,","sources":",us,","types":",geoserve,origin,phase-data,","nst":null,"dmin":3.2749999999999999,"rms":1.3100000000000001,"gap":116,"magType":"mww","type":"earthquake","title":"M 5.1 - 136km ESE of Pangai, Tonga"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-173.15700000000001,-20.294899999999998,10]},"id":"us70004pp5"}],"bbox":[-178.1173,-31.1748,10,149.5069,-6.0086,59.79]}

   var i = 0;

   document.writeln("<div class='right'>");
   for(i = 0;i<object.features.length;i++){

    var timestamp = object.features[i].properties.time / 1000;
    date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
    dateString = date.toUTCString();

    var today = date;
    today.setHours(today.getHours() + 4);

    /*datevalues = [
       date.getFullYear()+"-"+(date.getMonth()+1)+"-"+date.getDate(),
       date.getHours(),
       date.getMinutes(),
       date.getSeconds(),
    ];*/

    // maps


    document.writeln("<div class='list'>");
    document.writeln("<div>" + object.features[i].properties.mag + " Magnitude " + "</div>");

    /*document.writeln("<tr><td><b>Magnitude</b></td><td width = 50>" + object.features[i].properties.mag+"</td></tr>");
    document.writeln("<tr><td><b>Place</b></td><td width = 250>" + object.features[i].properties.place +"</td></tr>");
    document.writeln("<tr><td><b>Time</b></td><td width = 250>" + datevalues +"</td></tr>");
    document.writeln("<tr><td colspan = 2 style='background:#000;'>&nbsp;</td></tr>");*/

    document.writeln("</div>");

    /*var lat_var = object.features[i].geometry.coordinates[1];
    var lng_var = object.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0];
    var depth = object.features[i].geometry.coordinates[2];*/


   }
   document.writeln("</div>");



   require([
        "esri/Map",
        "esri/layers/GeoJSONLayer",
        "esri/views/MapView"
      ], function(Map, GeoJSONLayer, MapView) {
        // If GeoJSON files are not on the same domain as your website, a CORS enabled server
        // or a proxy is required.
        const url =
          "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2019-07-20&endtime=2019-07-21&minmagnitude=5";

        // Paste the url into a browser's address bar to download and view the attributes
        // in the GeoJSON file. These attributes include:
        // * mag - magnitude
        // * type - earthquake or other event such as nuclear test
        // * place - location of the event
        // * time - the time of the event
        // Use the Arcade Date() function to format time field into a human-readable format

        const template = {
          title: "Earthquake Info",
          content: "Magnitude {mag} {type} hit {place} on {time}",
          fieldInfos: [
            {
              fieldName: "time",
              format: {
                dateFormat: "short-date-short-time"
              }
            }
          ]
        };

        const renderer = {
          type: "simple",
          field: "mag",
          symbol: {
            type: "simple-marker",
            color: "orange",
            outline: {
              color: "white"
            }
          },
          visualVariables: [
            {
              type: "size",
              field: "mag",
              stops: [
                {
                  value: 2.5,
                  size: "4px"
                },
                {
                  value: 8,
                  size: "40px"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        };

        const geojsonLayer = new GeoJSONLayer({
          url: url,
          copyright: "USGS Earthquakes",
          popupTemplate: template,
          renderer: renderer //optional
        });

        const map = new Map({
          basemap: "gray",
          layers: [geojsonLayer]
        });

        for(i = 0;i<object.features.length;i++) {
          const view = new MapView({
            container: "viewDiv",
            center: [object.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0], object.features[0].geometry.coordinates[1]],
            zoom: 3,
            map: map
          });
        }
      });
```

Comment: To clarify, you are looking to trigger a click event and show the popup when you click the magnitude values in the box on the left hand side below the toggle zoom buttons?

Comment: @whyzar Yes. right